# merge/join two long df in R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, tidyr

I have two dataframes `a` and `b` which I would like to combine

```
a <- data.frame(g=c("1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4","4"),h=c("1","1","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","4"))

b <- data.frame(g=c("1","2","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","4"),i=c("1","2","3","2","1","2","3","4","5","6"))
```

`g` represents a grouping variable and `h` and `i` the columns I want to merge/join

```
> a
   g h
1  1 1
2  2 1
3  2 2
4  3 1
5  3 2
6  3 3
7  4 1
8  4 2
9  4 3
10 4 4

> b
   g i
1  1 1
2  2 2
3  3 3
4  3 2
5  3 1
6  4 2
7  4 3
8  4 4
9  4 5
10 4 6
```

`a` and `b` should be merged on the level of the grouping variable `g` whereas identical values of `h` and `i` should be put together (independant of the order they appear in `h`/`i`) and not identical values should be combined once (not all possible combinations).

a final `df` would look like:

```
   g    h    i
1  1    1    1
2  2    1 <NA>
3  2    2    2
4  3    1    1
5  3    2    2
6  3    3    3
7  4    1 <NA>
8  4    2    2
9  4    3    3
10 4    4    4
11 4 <NA>    5
12 4 <NA>    6
```

I need that df to perform a correlation analysis.

Comment: *"on the level of the grouping variable `a`"*. I don't see a grouping variable `a`. In your code example `a` is the full `data.frame`.

Comment: yes, `g` is the grouping variable. I corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a `merge` on `h==i`, while retaining `i`, so create a new variable `x` to join on, and keep join results from both sides (`all=TRUE`). With a large hat-tip to @Moody_Mudskipper:

```
merge(transform(a,x=h), transform(b,x=i), all=TRUE)

#   g x    h    i
#1  1 1    1    1
#2  2 1    1 <NA>
#3  2 2    2    2
#4  3 1    1    1
#5  3 2    2    2
#6  3 3    3    3
#7  4 1    1 <NA>
#8  4 2    2    2
#9  4 3    3    3
#10 4 4    4    4
#11 4 5 <NA>    5
#12 4 6 <NA>    6
```

Comment: more like `merge(transform(a,x=h), transform(b,x=i), all=TRUE)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper - nice. That matches what OP shows as their desired result, but doesn't seem to match their description about joining on `g`. I'll wait to see what they reckon, as I'm a little confused now.

Comment: @thelatemail maybe I confused you with my description, Moody_Mudskippers suggestion is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  mutate(x = h) %>%
  full_join(mutate(b, x = i)) %>%
  select(-x)
```